# Is there a place for posting "look at what I did" videos?

Tags: publications

Robots are somewhat videogenic, and the old saying "show me, don't tell me" is especially applicable.

But of course, a video is not a *question*, so it doesn't fit the Stack Exchange format.  Maybe video links would be more suitable in a CodeProject post.  It just seems like this board hits the right cross-section of people, whose projects I would be interested in seeing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Let's Make Robots](http://letsmakerobots.com/) is a good place to show off ones projects. See the [robots](http://letsmakerobots.com/view/node/list/robot) section to see other peoples work as well.

Comment: So implicitly, that won't be happening here.  Looks like a good site though, thanks.

Comment: Such a post would most certainly be closed since it wouldn't fit the Q&A format. See the [FAQ](http://robotics.stackexchange.com/faq#close) for more details.

Answer (score 2):

The AAAI video competition is a good yearly place to put them.  Otherwise, submitting them to IEEE Spectrum is a good idea as well.  Though its not the best robot news ever, it is the most consistent and most people in the industry check it at least weekly.

Answer (score 2):

While there are specific outlets, as the other answers show, you shouldn't underestimate plain old [YouTube](http://youtube.com). Most research labs and companies simply host their videos there (e.g. [MIT](https://www.youtube.com/user/mitmedialab), [BostonDynamics](https://www.youtube.com/user/BostonDynamics) and the likes), as do [individuals](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NqDTE6dHpJw).